# Find a vector from a magnitude?

Tags: vectors

I don't know if I am misunderstanding the question. How can I get the vector from the magnitude unless I know the direction of the vector that results in that magnitude?

> Find the vector c that has a magnitude of half that of the vector ${\bf b} = (-2,1,3)$.

So I get that the result $1/2||b|| = ||c||$

But I don't know how I am suppossed to find $c=(x,y,z)$? It could be multiple different answers.

Am I misunderstanding the question?

EDIT:

Yeah I think it is a poorly worded, sorry to bother you with this. I guess it might be helpful for someone who wants to know if you can find a vector from magnitude.

Comment: You can't determine a vector strictly from its magnitude so if you have no additional information the question is poorly posed.

Comment: The use of *the* instead of *a* (without any other information) shows the question isn't right. Otherwise, one might suppose that they mean that $b$ and $c$ are parallel.

Comment: Yeah I think it is a poorly  worded, sorry to bother you with this